# How to get the installed location of loaded library in R?

Tags: r

How to get the installed location of loaded library in R?

For example, I load the ggplots:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

what I want is the installed folder of the loaded ggplots.

```
folder = some_function(ggplot2)
```

Comment: `.libPaths()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `find.package()`.

```
find.package("ggplot2")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/ggplot2"
```